# Making changes to many files on a new branch - how to keep commits organized?

Tags: git, rebase

I'm currently making some big changes to the codebase in a new branch. It requires changing lots of files. I need to commit work in progress in order to merge from upstream but the code is not ready so what is the best practice here? Should I just use commit messages that are useful for me to know what stage I'm at and keep working that way and when branch is ready just rebase everything into one commit?

Comment: This is opinion-based. You could make "temporary" commits in your work branch, you could `stash` changes, you could `merge` frequently from `master`, you could regularly `rebase` your work onto `master`, you could do a large `rebase` at the end... Most of these have pros and cons, and the right choice for me might not be the right choice for you.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, if you *really* want the changes from upstream before your big changes in progress are over, then I would make a "temporary" commit, rebase, and reset, like this:

```
git add --all
git commit -m wip  # "work in progress"
git rebase upstream
git reset HEAD^    # undo the "work in progress" commit
```

Another alternative of the temporary commit is using `git stash` instead:

```
git add --all
git stash
git rebase upstream
git stash pop
```

As for squashing multiple commits into one, that's just a matter of taste. (I think multiple smaller commits are usually better than one giant commit.)

Comment: I like your the idea with stashing. I also prefer smaller commits but only if they're complete.